# increment trigger Update mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update

My table have 5 column : id,piece,tube,validate,index1
I want to increment the column validate of the next index1 who have the same tube and piece when I update the validate column (ONLY THE VALIDATE COLUMN) of the former row to 2 on my table.(I dont know if I can do that without trigger)

for exemple this is my table:

```
id  / piece / tube / validate / index1
__________________________________________________________________
1 / 1000/  / 011      / 1    / 1
2 / 1000/  / 011      / 0    / 2
3 / 1000/  / 011      / 0    / 3
4 / 1000/  / 011      / 0    / 4
```

my function update the "validate" column of the row with id=1
actual row validate+1=2 ->next row validate +1

```
id  / piece / tube / validate / index1
__________________________________________________________________
1 / 1000/  / 011      / 2    / 1
2 / 1000/  / 011      / 1    / 2
3 / 1000/  / 011      / 0    / 3
4 / 1000/  / 011      / 0    / 4
```

I did that trigger:

```
Create Trigger operationUp after update on operation 
for each Row 
begin 
    if validate =2 
       select new.index1+1 
       from operation 
       where piece=new.piece 
       and tube=new.tube;

       Update operation set validate=validate+1 
    end if; 
end;
```

But did not work

Comment: "But did not work" is not a problem description. Why didn't it work? Did you get an error? If so, what was the error message. Don't make us guess!

Comment: sry ,it's a syntax error "#1064- you have an error in your sql syntax;"

Comment: Makes sense; you've got a double `select`, and an apparent `update` statement without `update` ('Updateoperation').

Comment: sorry I did not write it correctly on stack I correct that

Comment: Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

Comment: What does your update statement look like for updating row 1?

Comment: my update statement only update the validate column of a row which increment , it work but I can't create my trigger. My trigger is there to update the next row

Answer (score 0):

As well as *Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger* you have syntax errors - 1) if has to have a then 2) every sql statement must be terminated with ; (you are missing one after the update statement) 3) you are not allowed to return a result set in a trigger (you cannot select, even if you know that only 1 value is returned the compiler won't let you try).